# Django's development server on Ubuntu not accessible via browser, only via -curl

Tags: django, ubuntu, curl, digital-ocean

I am trying to set up a Django website on an Ubuntu server hosted on DigitalOcean.
After following the step-by-step DigitalOcean tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

I remain stuck as I cannot seem to access Django's development server launched on 0.0.0:8000 with the browser of my local machine. However, I do have a response using -curl from the server's bash terminal. So it seems it can only be accessed from the server itself. Django does not return any error while launching the development server. It lists successful connections (code 200) every time I access it via -curl, but does not show anything when I try to access it via my external browser, as if it is actually not being acecssed.

What I did:

- followed this tutorial step-by-step until the launch of Django's development server,
- disabled Ubuntu's firewall and no DO firewall is used
- added '*' in ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: This probably is a proxy problem. However this is not a good question for SO.

Comment: How are you assessing it in your browser? Exactly what URL are you using?

Comment: I use the ip of the server, let’s say: http://123.45.67.89:8000/

Comment: Well, after accessing the IP address of the server from another Internet network, I could display the website. So it was probably a proxy issue, as mentioned.